# How to remove an element from a json with ruby?

Tags: arrays, json, ruby

For this json structs:

```
{
  "a_path": {
    "b_path": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "a"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "b"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Want to remove `id` element as:

```
{
    "a_path": {
      "b_path": [
        {
          "name": "a"
        },
        {
          "name": "b"
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

Is there a good way? I have tried:

```
$json_data = JSON.parse(response)["b_path"][0].delete("id")
```

But got this result:

```
"a_path": "1"
```

Comment: Your input is not a valid ruby nor json.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin Sorry, edited.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin: huh, what happened with the nickname? :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev that was a challenge: I decided to switch it to use my real name as soon as I got gold [tag:elixir] badge.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin then stick with elixir then and let normal humans get some rep on ruby... ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even if `.delete` would return the mutated hash (which it doesn't, it returns the deleted value), you are assigning `$json_data = JSON.parse(response)["b_path"][0]`.

Just assign the base hash, and mutate it in a loop with `.each`.

```
json_data = JSON.parse(response)
json_data['a_path']['b_path'].each { |h| h.delete('id') }
json_data
# => the expected hash
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the .delete method. It shoud return you the mutated hash but in actual it returns the deleted value. So only way is you need to assign the base hash and mutate it in a loop and call .delete within that